# How to display data between 2 dates in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to select and display data from a list between two dates. I input dates with data and I want to add a functionality to view the entries/data from the selected date to another selected date.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i have data in listView...i am perform search functionality in list view..i am input start date and end dates and show data instantly..plesae hlep..

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. Does your "data" consist of dates? Or are dates attached to every item of your data? Do you want to filter your data by a period of time? And please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Maybe you could post the code you have and tell us were you are having your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer, just a suggestion**
The best way to use is SQLite.
With SQLite, you can easily save data to a database and select between two points just like you want with two dates.
I don't know what have you implemented till now but this could be the best way to do what you want.